# How can I sort alphanumeric strings in Unix?

Tags: sorting, vim, editor

I have a list of table names, which are out of order. How can I get them in the correct logical order?

> `$ cat list.txt`

```
TAB1
TAB13
TAB11
TAB19
TAB2
TAB3
TAB16
TAB17
TAB18
TAB9
TAB10
TAB8
TAB12
TAB20
```

> `$ cat list.txt | sort -n`

```
TAB1
TAB10
TAB11
TAB12
TAB13
TAB16
TAB17
TAB18
TAB19
TAB2
TAB20
TAB3
TAB8
TAB9
```

Expected order:

```
TAB1
TAB2
TAB3
TAB8
TAB9
TAB10
TAB11
TAB12
TAB13
TAB16
TAB17
TAB18
TAB19
TAB20
```

Any vim short-cuts will also do, I do not necessarily need a separate utility for this.

Comment: Bookmarking because its such a fine question (with some fine answers)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to tell it where your sorting key starts:

```
sort -n -k1.4 list.txt
```

Otherwise it starts from the beginning, fails to convert a string to a number and falls back to alphabetical comparison.

Comment: It took me a bit to figure out how -k works: 1 is the field number and 4 is the character. If there was a space (the default field separator) after the T in TAB, then you'd use `sort -n -k2.4 list.txt`. You can use -t to specify custom field separators. `sort -n -tB -k2.1 list.txt` would also work because the B in TAB would divide the fields and we'd sort on the first character of the second field to the end of line.

Answer (score 41):

You can always perform sort with argument -V to sort alphanumeric string..

```
$ sort -V inputfile > outputfile

$ cat inputfile  
TAB1  
TAB13  
TAB11  
TAB19  
TAB2  
TAB3  
TAB16  
TAB17  
TAB18  
TAB9  
TAB10  
TAB8  
TAB12  
TAB20  

$ cat outputfile  
TAB1  
TAB2  
TAB3  
TAB8  
TAB9  
TAB10  
TAB11  
TAB12  
TAB13  
TAB16  
TAB17  
TAB18  
TAB19  
TAB20
```

Comment: You should mention that according to the manual, '-V' stands for "--version-sort" and is descrived as "natural sort of (version) numbers within text" -- taken from Ubuntu 20.04 standard repository. So it may not exactly behave as desired.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is tagged as a Vim question, I figured it might be worth mentioning the Vim option (even though I would personally use `sort` since the data's already in a file). It's simply

```
:sort n
```

Since Vim's numeric sort ignores up to the first decimal number, one doesn't need to ignore the "TAB" (`:sort` can take a pattern to ignore, `:sort n /TAB/` would work as well, for example). As usual, `:h :sort` for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know this. I had to go though a lot of pain of deleting the _string_, sort it and put back the _string_.

Comment: @jeffjose: That only works easily if you have the same string in all cases; it fails when you don't. The worst is when you can't pass the `sort -kX.Yn` shell command a fixed position. I've often had to write a Perl script to deal with those situations, and wish I didn't.  Similarly for sorting by the last field when there is a variable number of fields, although there you can just reverse the field order, sort it, then reverse it back again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Perl or any language where sort lets you specify a comparison operator:

`sub numcomp() {`

```
 $a =~ /([0-9]*)$/; $aa = $1;
 $b =~ /([0-9]*)$/; $bb = $1;
 $aa <=> $bb;
```

}

sort numcomp @mylist...

(Don't bother telling me it's baby Perl. I... um, I wrote it that way on purpose so it would be easy to understand.)
(Don't bother telling me it's wrong. I... um, I wrote it that way on purpose as an exercise for the reader.)