# sort alphanumerics using unix sort

Tags: linux, perl, sorting, unix, scripting

I have alphanumeric file containing following content

```
z1.doc
z10.doc
z100.doc
z101.doc
z102.doc
z11.doc
z12.doc
z13.doc
z14.doc
z15.doc
z16.doc
z17.doc
z18.doc
z19.doc
z2.doc
z20.doc
z3.doc
z4.doc
z5.doc
z6.doc
z7.doc
z8.doc
z9.doc
```

I want to sort it using unix/linux sort command to get the following output

```
z1.doc
z2.doc
z3.doc
z4.doc
z5.doc
z6.doc
z7.doc
z8.doc
z9.doc
z10.doc
z11.doc
z12.doc
z13.doc
z14.doc
z15.doc
z16.doc
z17.doc
z18.doc
z19.doc
z20.doc
z100.doc
z101.doc
z102.doc
```

I have used following commandline

```
sort -t "." -n -k1 sortAlphanumeric.txt
```

But output is not as required. Is it possible using sort command to sort this to get the required output or i should choose some other scripting language.

Comment: You should check [the following thread][1] with similar question


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33913/12641

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I sort alphanumeric strings in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279530/how-can-i-sort-alphanumeric-strings-in-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell sort that your key starts on position 2 and you want to sort numerically:

```
sort -k1.2n
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always perform sort with argument `-V` to sort alphanumeric string..

```
$ sort -V inputfile > outputfile

$ cat inputfile  
z1.doc  
z10.doc  
z100.doc  
z101.doc  
z102.doc  
z11.doc  
z12.doc  
z13.doc  
z14.doc  
z15.doc  
z16.doc  
z17.doc  
z18.doc  
z19.doc  
z2.doc  
z20.doc  
z3.doc  
z4.doc  
z5.doc  
z6.doc  
z7.doc  
z8.doc  
z9.doc    

$ cat outputfile
z1.doc  
z2.doc  
z3.doc  
z4.doc  
z5.doc  
z6.doc  
z7.doc  
z8.doc  
z9.doc  
z10.doc  
z11.doc  
z12.doc  
z13.doc  
z14.doc  
z15.doc  
z16.doc  
z17.doc  
z18.doc  
z19.doc  
z20.doc  
z100.doc  
z101.doc  
z102.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

cheat a little bit. say that the field delimiter is 'z' and sort numerically using second field.

```
sort -t z -k 2 -n < fff
z1.doc
z2.doc
z3.doc
z4.doc
z5.doc
z6.doc
z7.doc
z8.doc
z9.doc
z10.doc
z11.doc
z12.doc
z13.doc
z14.doc
z15.doc
z16.doc
z17.doc
z18.doc
z19.doc
z20.doc
z100.doc
z101.doc
z102.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to figure out where the number/letter boundaries are in advance for your data, you can use the module [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) and natsort

```
perl -MSort::Key::Natural -e "print natsort <>" sortAlphanumeric.txt
```

Comment: Converted solution to [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural) from [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) because of the latter ignores non-word characters.