# how to sort alphanumeric string linux bash *

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, alphanumeric

**list.txt:**

```
af3400

af3500

cdf666

bgh400

bgfn44

123456

788000

567890
```

**output.txt:**

```
af3400

af3500

bgfn44

bgh400

cdf666

123456

567890

788000
```

please help

Comment: You are looking for the "sort" command

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I sort alphanumeric strings in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279530/how-can-i-sort-alphanumeric-strings-in-unix)

Comment: i try this comand but only order in numerical form

Comment: in this post How can I sort alphanumeric strings in Unix?  the command uses the phrase "tab" for  order in numeric  form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort` with `-g` option:

```
sort -g list.txt
```

`-g` to put letters (a-z) before numbers (0-9)

To get output in a file:

```
sort -g list.txt -o output.txt
```

Or

```
sort -g list.txt > output.txt
```