# How to order the following list by numerical value?

Tags: bash

Hello I have the following list:

```
D10
D7
D8
D9
SUB1
SUB11
SUB12
SUB13
SUB15
SUB16
SUB17
SUB18
SUB19
SUB2
SUB20
SUB21
SUB22
SUB23
SUB24
SUB25
SUB26
SUB27
SUB28
SUB3
SUB31
SUB34
SUB35
SUB42
SUB43
SUB5
SUB6
```

I would like to order it by numerical value I mean just using the numbers at the end of the strings I tried:

```
sort -n < list_ORDER
```

But I got:

```
D10
D7
D8
D9
SUB1
SUB11
SUB12
SUB13
SUB15
SUB16
SUB17
SUB18
SUB19
SUB2
SUB20
SUB21
SUB22
SUB23
SUB24
SUB25
SUB26
SUB27
SUB28
SUB3
SUB31
SUB34
SUB35
SUB42
SUB43
SUB5
SUB6
```

I would like to appreciate any suggestion, thanks a lot for the support

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279530/how-can-i-sort-alphanumeric-strings-in-unix

Comment: `grep -o -E '[0-9]+' <your-text-file-name>| sort -g` will sort the numbers (not the full text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking help  from `sed` to space separate non-digit characters from digits, `sort`-ing based on the numeric field and then join them back:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:digit:]]*)([[:digit:]]*)$/\1 \2/' file.txt | sort -k2,2n | sed 's/ //'
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^[:digit:]]*)([[:digit:]]*)$/\1 \2/' file.txt | sort -k2,2n | sed 's/ //'
SUB1
SUB2
SUB3
SUB5
SUB6
D7
D8
D9
D10
SUB11
SUB12
SUB13
SUB15
SUB16
SUB17
SUB18
SUB19
SUB20
SUB21
SUB22
SUB23
SUB24
SUB25
SUB26
SUB27
SUB28
SUB31
SUB34
SUB35
SUB42
SUB43
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split letters with numbers and then sort:

```
sed -e 's/\([^0-9]\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/\1 \2/' | sort -k2 -n | sed -e 's/ //'
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.